# Как запустить приложение java из другого

Tags: java

У меня есть код:

```
public class Console extends Thread {
private static boolean run;
private TreeMap<Integer, String> commandMap = new TreeMap<>();
private ArrayList<String> query = new ArrayList<>();
private Process proc;
private BufferedReader in, err;
private PrintWriter out;

private int index;
private int currentIndex;

private Main main;

public Console(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
    setName("Console");
}

@Override
public void start() {
    if(run) {
        Dialog.show("Ошибка", "Сервер уже запущен!");
        return;
    }
    main.cons_console.clear();
    super.start();
}

public void stopConsole() {
    run = false;
    proc.destroy();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        run = true;
        ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder(pathParser(Main.settings.lines)); //new ProcessBuilder("java", "-cp {path}");

        b.directory(new File(Main.settings.corePath).getParentFile());
        b.redirectErrorStream(true);
        proc = b.start();

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(proc.getOutputStream());

        query q = new query();
        process p = new process();
        error e = new error();
        q.setName("Console [Query]");
        p.setName("Console [Process]");
        e.setName("Console [Error]");

        q.start();
        p.start();
        e.start();
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        Dialog.showStacktrace("Ошибка", "Ошибка при запуске консоли", t);
        main.stopServ();
    }
}

public String backCommand() {
    String s = commandMap.get(currentIndex);
    if(currentIndex > 0) currentIndex--;
    return s;
}

public String forwardCommand() {
    String s = commandMap.get(currentIndex);
    if(currentIndex < index) currentIndex++;
    return s;
}

public void onInsert(String value) {
    query.add(value);
}

private String[] pathParser(String[] parse) {
    String[] str = new String[parse.length + 1];
    str[0] = "java";

    for(int i = 1;i < parse.length + 1;i++) {
        str[i] = parse[i - 1].replace("{path}", Main.settings.corePath).replace("java ", "");
        System.out.println(str[i]);

    }
    return str;
}
public class query extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while(run) {
            try {
                for (String s : query) {
                    out.write(s);
                    main.cons_console.appendText("> " + s);

                    commandMap.put(index, s);

                    if (currentIndex == index) currentIndex++;
                    index++;
                }
                query.clear();
            } catch(Throwable t) {
                Dialog.showStacktrace("Ошибка", "Ошибка при обработке очереди", t);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class process extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            String str;
            while (run && ((str = in.readLine()) != null)) {
                main.cons_console.appendText(" -> " + str + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Dialog.showStacktrace("Ошибка", "Ошибка при обработке входящих данных", t);
        }
    }
}

public class error extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            String str;
            while (run && ((str = err.readLine()) != null)) {
                main.cons_console.appendText(" ->>> " + str + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Dialog.showStacktrace("Ошибка", "Ошибка при обработке ошибок", t);
        }
    }
}
```

Должен запускать программу. Также в неё можно что-то ввести.
Но я получаю это: (Запуск сервера Minecraft(Да я школо))

```
 -> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
 -> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
 -> Unrecognized option: -cp C:\Users\ender\Desktop\devServer\core.jar
```

Помогите, пожалуйста

P.S Не бейте тапками за плохой код)

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение, я запускал так: new ProcessBuilder(pathParser(Main.settings.lines)).start();

а надо было сменить String[] pathParser(String[] s); на String[] parse(String s);

Но пришлось сделать запуск процесса в 1 строку.
Получилось:

```
    private String[] parse(String s) {
      String s1 = s.replace("{path}", Main.settings.corePath);
      System.out.println(s1);
      return s1.split(" ");
    }
```

запускаю теперь так: `new ProcessBuilder(parse(Main.settings.runLine)).start();`